# Remoção de linhas com níveis não repetidos em R

Tags: r

Galera, tenho o seguinte df:

```
df <- data.frame(X =c("a","b","c","a","b","c","a","b","c","d","a","b","c","d","e"),
 Y = c("w","w","w", "K","K","K", "L","L","L","L","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z"))
```

Notem que o primeiro vetor tem 5 níveis e o segundo tem 4 níveis. Meu objetivo é selecionar as linhas do `df` que possuem todos os níveis do vetor 1 em comum como o vetor 2. Ou seja, quero selecionar as linhas que tenham os níveis "a","b" e "c", uma vez que "d" só aparece duas vezes "e" aparece uma vez no vetor 1.

Tentei fazer uma lista com os níveis em comum e deixar somente as linhas com os níveis em comum por `subset`. No entanto, não dá certo porque essa lista com níveis não gera o endereço das linhas que quero remover. Ex:

```
comuns <- c("a","b","c")
df2 <- df[c(comuns),]
```

No meu `df` real há 64 níveis em comum, então não rola fazer "na bruta". Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Eu não consegui compreender o que significa a frase "selecionar as linhas do `df` que possuem todos os níveis do vetor 1 em comum como o vetor 2". Em particular, não vejo como esta frase virou a frase seguinte: "selecionar as linhas que tenham os níveis 'a', 'b' e 'c'". Vetor 1 é a coluna X? Vetor 2 é a coluna Y? Neste caso, não consigo entender como X e Y podem ter níveis em comum neste exemplo específico. Seria interessante editar a pergunta e colocar a resposta esperada.

Comment: Isso, Marcus. Vetor 1 é a coluna X e Vetor 2 é a coluna Y. Já consegui resolver o problema com a ajuda dos colegas abaixo. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> df[df$X %in% comuns, ]
   X Y
1  a w
2  b w
3  c w
4  a K
5  b K
6  c K
7  a L
8  b L
9  c L
11 a Z
12 b Z
13 c Z
```

## Encontrando os elementos comuns:

```
tabF <- table(df$X, df$Y)
comuns <- rownames(tabF)[apply(tabF > 0, 1, all)]

> comuns
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

Comment: Resolvi, Carlos. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Mais um. `table(df)` é mais simples.